# UserWarning: X has feature names, but GaussianNB was fitted without feature names

Tags: classification, gaussian, text-classification, feature-selection, naivebayes

I'm getting this message during model fitting 'UserWarning: X has feature names, but GaussianNB was fitted without feature names'
How to solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. `X` is a DataFrame
```
        X_train, y_train = X.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[train_index]
        scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
        X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train), columns=X.columns)
        
        # Fit the model
        gridsearch = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000), params, cv=cv, verbose=1, n_jobs=-4)
        gridsearch.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values) 
```

Answer (score 0):

Use X_train or X_test, but put X_train.values or X_test.values.  This is because is a dataframe not a numpy.ndarray